# Outsourced python module doesn't update globals

Tags: python, import, global

I am adding some global variables inside a class. The below works fine:

```
class AssignGlobal():

    @staticmethod
    def assign():
        code = 'xyz'
        index = 2
        globals()[code] = index

AssignGlobal.assign()

xyz  ## returns 2
```

But if I outsource the AssignGlobal class, the globals don't get updated any more. I am actually not sure what this import actually does exactly. Why doesn't it update my globals?

```
from backtester.outsourced import AssignGlobal as ag
## assume I created a file outsourced.py in the backtested subdirectory from where I am. It contains the AssignGlobal class above

ag.assign()

xyz
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8714e0ef31ed> in <module>
----> 1 xyz

NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python global variables are essentially scoped to the module they are defined in.

When you declare a global variable inside a module they get added to the module `__dict__` and can be accessed from another module as a attribute.

In your case the module where you are importing the `outsourced` module will not have the `xyz` in its `__dict__` , rather the `outsourced` module object will have an attribute `xyz` set after you call `AssignGlobal.assign()`.

The following code will output `2`:

```
import outsourced

outsourced.AssignGlobal.assign()

print(outsourced.xyz)
```

The reason is, when `assign` is called the `xyz` is defined in the scope of the `outsourced` module not where it is imported as global variables are not shared.

To get the `xyz` value you need to fetch it as an attribute from the `outsourced` module object.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) shows how you can share variables across modules.

Comment: That would do, but is there no- perhaps non-canonical-  way to "download" the global variables from the other module to the main module's globals, as to avoid having to use a prefix?

Comment: @DISC-O you can assign it to a global variable and name it `xyz`